# Pixelated SVG in Chrome only with "background-repeat: repeat-y"

Tags: svg

In the [following Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7835zno/) you'll notice the SVG becomes pixelated, however it only becomes pixelated when `background-repeat: repeat-y` is applied. Uncommenting the line above where there's `no-repeat` will render the SVG perfectly.

What is the cause of this? Is it a bug in Chrome, or is the SVG to blame? I've tried applying `preserveAspectRatio` to both `none` and `xMaxYMax` but that doesn't seem to correct it.

Comment: Have you found a fix to this issue?